# Is a public static final int thread safe?

Tags: java, thread-safety

I want to have a file with constants being accessed from multiple threads. Is it a safe implementation to have a class with a lot of `public static final int`s for this?

Comment: In general (unless you go out of your way to make it untrue), a class is completely initialized before you can reference anything in it, so static initializations will be visible from other threads, without any explicit synchronization on your part.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is thread-safe. Any `static final` variable is guaranteed to be initialized after class initialization. Thus, once a class containing such a `static final` variable is used anywhere in your code, it is always fully initialized (i.e. the value is set) by [requirement of the JVMS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.5).

With a primitive `int`, this condition is even tighter. A primitive `static final` variable (same goes for `String`) is a so called [*compile-time constant*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28) which are inlined by the Java compiler *javac*. The only requirement is that the value can be computed by the Java compiler, i.e. it must not be the result of a non-constant evaluation. As you are write that you want to define *constants*, I assume that this does not apply for your use case. Those constant values are therefore directly copied to their access location what cuts the corner-case of non-thread safety of a `static final` variable being altered via reflection wich is hypothetically an issue with non-primitive types.

Furthermore, using such variables is a good idea because it avoids the use of so-called [*magic numbers*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29).

Comment: `static final` doesn't automatically makes field *compile time constant*. It depends on how we initialized it (if it is result of method which would read data from file then its value will be set at runtime which means compiler can't know about it).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is safe.

The value never changes so there is no risk of race conditions. Java guarantees that the value will be initialized before anything tries to use it.

Whether it is the best architecture for other reasons (clarity of design etc) is another question.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, 100% safe. It's final, so nobody can alter it. Every thread has to access as reader only, and there is no contention for reading only.

Comment: `final` variables can be altered easily using reflection (or code generation since `final` variables are not enforced by the JVM.)

Answer (score 1):

For *primitives*, making them `final` makes them *compile time constants* (if initialized directly and not as result of method) and an `int` is a *primitive*. So, `final int` makes it *immutable* and hence *thread-safe*.

Comment: "For *primitives*, making them `final` makes them *compile time constants*" you are almost there but that is not end of the story. To create *compile time constant* beside proper declaration you need also proper initialization. In this case value must be put directly, It can't be result of some method which will for instance read it from file (which would have to happen at runtime which means compiler will not be able to know about it).

Comment: "and not as method / expression result" expressions are OK if they are based on other *compile time constants*. Compiler will change `1+2+3` to `6` and `"foo"+"bar"` will be compiled into `"foobar"`.

Comment: @Pshemo - but String a = "a" ; String b ="b"; String s =a+b will be  determined during compile-time only if both a and b are final. I was considering this example.

Comment: I didn't say all expressions are OK, only those based on compile time constants.